# Cannot pull data from XML files due to differences in format

Tags: python, xml, keyerror, xmltodict

I have a script that takes a bunch of XML files, all in the form of: `HMDB61152.xml` and pulls them all in using `glob`. For each file I need to pull some details about each, such as `accession`, `name`, and a list of `diseases`. To parse through each XML I used `xmltodict` because I traditionally like working with lists instead of XML files, although I may need to change my strategy due to the issues I am facing.

I am able to pull `name` and `acc` easily since all XML files have it in the same first level of the tree:

p`ath = '/Users/me/Downloads/hmdb_metabolites'
for data_file in glob.glob(os.path.join(path,'*.xml')):
    diseases=[]
    with open(data_file) as fd:
        doc = xmltodict.parse(fd.read())
        name = doc['metabolite']['name']
        acc = doc['metabolite']['accession']`

So basically at this point there are three options for the disease information:

1. There are multiple `disease` tags within each `diseases` tree. I.e there are 2 or more diseases for the given accession.
2. There is one `disease` within the `diseases` tree meaning the accession has only one disease.
   or
3. There are no `disease` in the `diseases` tree at all.

I need to write a loop that can handle any three cases, and thats where I am failing. Here is my approach so far:

```
    #I get the disease root, which returns True if it has lower level items (one or more disease within diseases) 
#or False if there are no disease within diseases. 
    dis_root=doc['metabolite']['diseases']
    if (bool(dis_root)==True):
        dis_init = doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease']
        if (bool(doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease'][0]) == True):
            for x in range(0,len(dis_init)):
                diseases.append(doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease'][x]['name'])
        else: 
            diseases.append(doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease']['name'])

    else:
        diseases=['None']
```

So the problem is, for the case where there are multiple diseases, I need to pull their names in the following format: `doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease'][x]['name']` for each x in diseases. But for the ones that have only one disease, they have no index at all, so the only way I can pull the name of that one disease is by doing `doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease']['name']`.

The script is failing because as soon as we encounter a case of only one disease, it returns a KeyError when it tries to test if `doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease'][0]) == True`. If anyone can help me figure this out that'd be great, or direct me to a more appropriate strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
if 0 in doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease']:
    pass # if 0 is a key in the array, we have multiple entries
else
    pass # only a single item.
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a relatively easy workaround, I simply use try in the following way:

```
try:
            for x in range(0,len(dis_init)):
                    diseases.append(doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease'][x]['name'])
            except KeyError: 
                diseases.append(doc['metabolite']['diseases']['disease']['name'])
```